# LibGDX. Android. Black background on transparent DecalSprites

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, libgdx, sprite

In my App I use several DecalSprites as a part of my scene. They all have transparency (PNG-textures). When I have them overlapping, some of those show black background instead of transparency. Those DecalSprites have different Z-coordinates. So they should look like one behind another.

[image]

Please note also the line on the border of a texture. This is also something that I'm struggling to remove.

**Update 1:** I use PerspectiveCamera in the scene. But all the decals are positioned to face the camera as in 2d mode. So this "black" background appears only in certain cases e.g. when camera goes right (and all those decals appear in the left of the scene). Also I use the CameraGroupStrategy

Comment: can you confirm that some are being displayed correctly and some arent? or are they all being displayed incorrectly?

Comment: Are you using a custom version of GroupStrategy, or one of the included ones? If using a custom GroupStrategy, please show the code.

Comment: If you are using a texture atlas, the line on the border of the texture is probably from not using enough padding when packing your atlas.

Comment: Have you made any direct calls to `gl` involving depth testing or depth writing? What blend function are you using when creating the Decals?

Comment: I'll update the question with sources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! The reason was that CameraGroupStrategy when ordering Decals (from farthest to closest to camera) takes the "combined" vector distance between camera and the Decal. When my camera panned to left or to right the distance to the Z-farthest Decal became LESS than the Z-closer Decal. This produced the artifact. Fix:

```
GroupStrategy strategy = new CameraGroupStrategy(cam , new ZStrategyComparator());
```

And the Comparator:

```
    private class ZStrategyComparator implements Comparator<Decal> {

    @Override
    public int compare (Decal o1, Decal o2) {
        float dist1 = cam.position.dst(0, 0, o1.getPosition().z);
        float dist2 = cam.position.dst(0, 0, o2.getPosition().z);
        return (int)Math.signum(dist2 - dist1);
    }

}
```

Thanks to all guys who tried to help. Especially Xoppa. He sent me into the right direction in libGDX IRC.